# stuck on mysql installation

Tags: mysql, installation

When I am installing mysql on centOS 7, on the step where it needs to type `yum install mysql-server` command, it is giving me these error messages:

```
Error: Package: mysql-community-client-5.6.31-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-libs-5.6.31-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.6.31-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.6.31-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: mysql-community-server-5.6.31-2.el7.x86_64 (mysql56-community)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.17)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You can refer this https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7............here is solution step wise from beginning

Comment: @PiyushGupta remake link please

Comment: @DimitrieMititelu, https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/mysql/how-to-install-mysql-on-centos-7